# Creating a windows 8 virtualbox image doesn't work. VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED error occurs

Tags: windows, installation, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm trying to create a Virtualbox image of windows 8 consumer preview. I tried this tutorial: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-windows-8-on-virtualbox/

I did exactly what was said in that tutorial. At the step "Now navigate to the Windows 8 developer build ISO file that you downloaded and select it." I get the error "Could not get the storage format. (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)". I also get this if I use the regular wizard.

Host OS: windows 7
Virtualbox version: 4.1.14

Both windows 8 64 bit and 32 bit tested.

EDIT: tested on Virtualbox version 4.1.16, the error still occured.

Comment: Before you do anything else, update to the latest (4.1.16) and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my Virtualbox, it didn't solve the error.

Comment: Maybe your .iso is corrupt. Can you try mounting it somewhere and see if you can browse the content? Or search for the MD5 hash and check.

Comment: I tried to re-download, it didn't solve the problem. If I mount the disk, the setup starts. When started I get this error: "Installing Windows 8 error msg: A DVD driver your PC needs is missing."

Comment: @MichelZ - Corrupt ISOs is not the problem.  No one who has gotten this error has resolved it from all that I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, Windows 8 isn't supported on VirtualBox prior to version 4.2 (which is almost ready for release as write this). That being said, many people have had success running Win8 on the 4.1.x series.

The key things that you must have support present in your host hardware / OS and enabled on your guest configuration:

- Enable IO APIC in the guest settings
- Change the chipset to ICH9 from PIIX3 default
- Enable PAE/NX for the virtual processor(s)
- Enable VT-x / AMD-V
- Enable Nested Paging

That should be enough to get it to boot. Once you have a working combination, you can also enable 2D and 3D acceleration and boost the video RAM - though the guest additions have some issues to iron out (thus not being fully supported until VBox 4.2).

Comment: That explains a lot, got it running now. Cheers!